# HTML div table and css

Tags: html, css-tables

I'm trying to create a table using DIV tags and CSS but I don't understand why, when I have small screen, I see all rows with the same width, but when I view them on a larger screen I do not.

Html code:

```
<div class="rTable">
<div class="rTableRow">
    <div class="rTableHeadInc1">Rif.</div>
    <div class="rTableHeadInc2">Realizzazione incentivata nell&#8217;anno</div>
    <div class="rTableHeadInc3">Numero di richieste accettate</div>
    <div class="rTableHeadInc4">Importo versato [CHF]</div>
</div>
<div class="rTableRow">
    <div class="rTableCellInc1">ID1</div>
    <div class="rTableCellInc2">Allacciamento a reti di teleriscaldamento</div>
    <div class="rTableCellInc3">
        <input type="text" name="ID1NumAccept" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="rTableCellInc4">
        <input type="text" name="ID1Pay" value="" onblur="isNumber(this);" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="rTableRow">
    <div class="rTableCellInc1">ID2</div>
    <div class="rTableCellInc2">Altri ambiti legati alla distribuzione
        <br/>
        <input type="text" name="ID2OtherDesc" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="rTableCellInc3">
        <input type="text" name="ID2NumAccept" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="rTableCellInc4">
        <input type="text" name="ID2Pay" value="" onblur="isNumber(this);" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
    input[type="text"] {
    width: 85%;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.rTable {
    display: table;
    width: 70%;
    height:100%;
}
.rTableRow {
    clear: both;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.rTableHeadInc1 {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #DDD;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    height:100%;
    width: 10%;
}
.rTableHeadInc2 {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #DDD;
    font-weight: bold;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    height:100%;
    width: 36%;
}
.rTableHeadInc3 {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #DDD;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    height:100%;
    width: 27%;
}
.rTableHeadInc4 {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #DDD;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    height:100%;
    width: 27%;
}
.rTableCellInc1 {
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    display: table-cell;
    height:100%;
    width: 10%;
}
.rTableCellInc2 {
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    display: table-cell;
    height:100%;
    width: 36%;
}
.rTableCellInc3 {
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    display: table-cell;
    height:100%;
    width: 27%;
    text-align:center;
}
.rTableCellInc4 {
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    height:100%;
    width: 27%;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle link to my html and css: http://jsfiddle.net/cgxwt1dp/2/

Can someone help me please?

Comment: That looks like tabular data .. you could always just use a `<table>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's missing the `table-row` value, try this and see if it helps.

```
.rTableRow {
    display:table-row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned you forgotten the `.rTableRow` class.
Just uploading the jsfiddle for you so you can see, i've made the class blue:)

http://jsfiddle.net/Katherina/cgxwt1dp/3/

Saluti!

Answer (score 0):

I would use regular old tables and save yourself the headache.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgxwt1dp/5/)

**html**

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <th>Rif.</th>
    <th>Realizzazione incentivata nell&#8217;anno</th>
    <th>Numero di richieste accettate</th>
    <th>Importo versato [CH]</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>ID1</td>
    <td>Allacciamento a reti di teleriscaldamento</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="ID1NumAccept" value="" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="ID1Pay" value="" onblur="isNumber(this);" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>ID2</td>
    <td>Altri ambiti legati alla distribuzione
        <br/>
        <input type="text" name="ID2OtherDesc" value="" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="ID2NumAccept" value="" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="ID2Pay" value="" onblur="isNumber(this);" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="text"] {
    width: 85%;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
table{
    width:70%;
    border:0;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
th {
    background-color: #DDD;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align:left;
}
th, td{
    vertical-align:top;
    padding:2px;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    border-left:0;
    border-top:0;
}
th:first-child, td:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid #999999;
    width:10%;
}
tr:first-child th{
    border-top: 1px solid #999999;
}
th:nth-child(2){
    width:36%;

}
th:nth-child(3) ,th:nth-child(4) {
    width:27%;    
}
td:nth-child(3) ,td:nth-child(4) {
    text-align:center;
}
```